# Single writer memory visibility guarantee on single processor

Tags: c++, multithreading

For the below C++ code

```
volatile bool keepRunning = true;

void run() {
    while (keepRunning) {
        doSomeWork();
    }
}

void stop() {
    keepRunning = false;
}
```

suppose one thread executes stop() and multiple threads are executing run()

I believe this kind of construct (one writer, no synchronization primitives) is quite prevalent in embedded systems. Is this guaranteed to work, assuming there's no multiple processors/cores?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because on a unicore machine there is only one CPU and one CPU-cache.

Another reason: To the CPU, it looks like there is only one thread running. The CPU is obliged to present the application a view of memory which is equivalent to single-threaded execution because the CPU can't even tell that there are multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

No, memory barriers are not imposed in your code, so the compiler is free to re-order volatile access with non-volatile ones, which might lead to incorrect behavior. 'volatile' has very little to do with multi-threading, for more information look at [Arch Robison's blog post](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/).

Also this is irrelevant if this is a single CPU platform or multiple CPU one, if the code is correct, then store-with-release will propagate to other CPUs/threads through cache coherency protocol and all will be fine.